# Issue parsing variable from HTML with bs4

Tags: beautifulsoup

Im trying to parse the "value" of variable ( __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR ), here's the HTML code ::

```
<div>
<input id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" type="hidden" value="1434571F"/>
</div>
```

Here's the code I am attempting to do that with ::

```
viewstategenerator = soup.findAll("input", {"type": "hidden", "name": "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"})
```

I then execute:: print(viewstategenerator), and I get the following string for my variable:

```
>>> print(viewstategenerator)
[<input id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" type="hidden" value="1434571F"/>]
```

I was expecting to grab just the value of "1434571F", not sure why that is... Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're close but just a tad confused about the BeautifulSoup API.

`soup.findAll` returns a *list* of all of the DOM elements that match the query you gave it. Seeing as only one element on the page can match your query, you should use `soup.find` instead. To get the value of the `value` attribute of your `input` element, use `['value']`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

html = """
<div>
<input id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" type="hidden" value="1434571F"/>
</div>
"""

soup = Soup(html, 'lxml') # Use whatever parser you're already using.


viewstategenerator = soup.find("input", {"type": "hidden", "name": "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"})
print(viewstategenerator['value'])
# Prints 1434571F
```